# error 416 Requested range not satisfiable

Tags: c, http

[image: error image]

I'm getting 416 Requested range not satisfiable while doing FOTA in teraterm and i'm requesting using HTTP could you please explain why this error coming
need a solution for this error

Comment: If there is any C code involved, then please show it. If not, then please remove the C language tag.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question and show the code or command you run and the output *as text*. What device is FOTA related to?